# Java Program to sort string of arrays

Tags: java, string, algorithm, sorting, collections

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        getWords("i m very very happy");

    }

    private static TreeSet<String> getWords(String str) {

        char a[] = str.toCharArray();
        String smallWords = "";
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

            if (a[i] != ' ') {
                smallWords = smallWords + a[i];
            } else {
                char sortedA[] = smallWords.toCharArray();
                Arrays.sort(sortedA);
                String sortedString = new String(sortedA);
                words.add(sortedString);
                smallWords = "";
            }

        }

        System.out.println("words :: " + words);
        TreeSet<String> sortedWords = new TreeSet<>(words);
        System.out.println("sortedWords :: " + sortedWords);
        return sortedWords;
    }
}
```

In above code I was able to code the right output with every word sorted of a string array but my output was [ervy, i, m] where last word happy is missing. Can someone please guide what logic I have to use so last word of the array should also reflect in my output.

Comment: The code that adds `sortedString` to `words` is only executed when you reach a space in the string. Given there's no space at the end of the string it's never executed for the final word.

Comment: Please include the proper import statements. It is much easier to help you if I can paste it into the debugger and get to where you are without having to debug the imports.

Comment: While learning to write programs, it's equally important to learn the programming tools. Have a look at your IDE's debugging features, and single-step through your program. Watching your variables, you'll surely see where things get messed up.

Comment: You can use [`indexOf(' ')`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) and [`indexOf(' ', previousPosition + 1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,int)) to find the word delimiters and use [`getChars`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#getChars(int,int,char%5B%5D,int)) to copy their contents into a char array, instead of looping over all characters and build new strings, just for calling `toCharArray()` on them.

Answer (score 0):

As @sprinter commented: "he code that adds sortedString to words is only executed when you reach a space in the string. Given there's no space at the end of the string it's never executed for the final word."

One option to fix that would be to break your `if` statement up into the piece that handles spaces and the piece that processes the words.:

```
for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    // if not space add to smallWords
    if (a[i] != ' ') {
        smallWords = smallWords + a[i];
    }
    // if space or last character, process smallWords
    if (a[i] == ' ' || i==a.length-1)  { 
        char sortedA[] = smallWords.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(sortedA);
        String sortedString = new String(sortedA);
        words.add(sortedString);
        smallWords = "";
    }
}
```

**result:**

> words :: [i, m, ervy, ervy, ahppy]
> sortedWords :: [ahppy, ervy, i, m]